# Icemaker entirely empty, not making ice

Tags: refrigerator, ice-maker

I have a GE side-by-side fridge with bottom freezer. It has an IMC-701 icemaker. It looks very very close to [this icemaker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otRCvnv3I20&t=5s) from a Samsung freezer. It is entirely empty.

I've checked/tried:

- The water filter - there's none, it has a bypass plug, and water comes out of the water dispenser just fine
- The inlet hose - seems clear of ice
- For ice dams - there's no ice anywhere
- The fridge temp - set to 38 for fridge, -2 for freezer
- Pressing the "test button" and holding it for five seconds. Nothing happens.
- The ice detection arm - maybe it's stuck in the up position? I cannot see any way of making it come down, as the spring pushes it up every time as if it were intended to always be up.

In addition I should note that there's something dripping ice into the compartment of the fridge. I've cleaned out the drain valve recently, but there's still a layer of ice sitting on the bottom of the fridge.

Does anyone have a video of how the ice detection arm should be working on this particular model? Or any other tips or things to check?

Pictures:
[image: Icemaker arm]
[image: Icemaker arm down]

Comment: Often there is a reset switch.  Have you looked for it?

Comment: @jwh20 according to [Caesar's Appliances](https://www.caesarsapplianceservice.com/blog/reset-samsung-refrigerator-ice-maker/) the test button is the reset button. I held it for 10 seconds and received no feedback - no chime, no motor moving - but it says to wait 24 hours from that, so I guess I'll check back tomorrow.

Comment: No progress on it doing anything.

Comment: I googled that IMC-701 icemaker. Have you looked at Google's result. The section that provides similar questions, lists several things you can try in trouble shooting.

Comment: Follow up on the ice detection arm.   Try holding down with a rubber band.  Sometimes they are installed incorrectly, or one end of the arm has fallen out and the icemaker 'thinks' that the arm is up and thus that the ice bin is full

Answer (score 4):

Even without the model# for your fridge and searched *IMC-701 icemaker troubleshooting,* I did find this at [hunker.com](https://www.hunker.com/13409903/how-to-reset-the-ice-maker-on-a-ge-side-by-side-refrigerator) that might help:

> ***GE Ice Maker Isn't Working***
> When your GE refrigerator isn't making ice, you'll first want to identify the shutoff switch for your refrigerator's ice maker. Shut off this part of the appliance and leave it off for at least 30 seconds.
>
> While the power is off, locate the arm within the ice maker, which is a thick wire. This arm, also called a feeler, is what tells the unit to stop producing ice when it comes into contact with ice cubes. Restore power to the ice maker.
>
> Next, push up on the arm or feeler three times. This will reset the unit. Restore all power and attempt to run an ice-making cycle. If it works, you're all set. If not, be sure that nothing is clogging the ice machine chute and try the entire process again if ice cubes were lodged inside.

This only a smaller portion of that page, so it's worth a look.

Comment: I thought all the IMC-701 icemakers were the same, so I didn't post the model, but here it is: GFSS6KKYASS.

Comment: This icemaker does not have one of the wire arms that the others do, so I don't know how to push up or down on the wire arm. It has a springloaded plastic slotted spoon-like arm that I wonder if it's the equivalent. I'll add pictures to the post.

Comment: I have tried turning it off and on again, and pulling down on the slotted spoon arm 3 times.

Comment: @freyley well sometimes it can help..i did find this video about Samsung's https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrloHZis2NM looks like same icemaker. and this.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrloHZis2NM Just the model # search gave me this: https://www.geapplianceparts.com/store/parts/assembly/GFSS6KKYASS

Answer (score 0):

There might be something frozen inside you can't see.

**Let it thaw out for of couple of hours with the door open.**   But first eat any and all the ice cream.

Comment: Keep in mind that in a typical side-by-side refrigerator/freezer, the temperatures of the two sections are linked. If you leave the freezer open, the refrigerator may get too warm for safety. If you have an "extra" refrigerator, move everything down there temporarily. If not, get a cooler/ice chest and fill it up with some ice and the most perishable stuff (i.e., meat, dairy, etc. - don't worry about fruits/veg. & drinks (except milk)).

Comment: ***ice cream***

Comment: I've lived in homes I was renovating. After the 2nd or 3rd faulty fridge, I have learned to keep a standard ice cooler at the ready.

Answer (score 0):

This video about how to debug an icemaker failure with a voltmeter is potentially helpful, but I haven't figured out which kind the IMC-701 is, so I haven't taken it apart and tried it yet. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWgZg8BD21o